# Bash giving me : Too many arguments error

Tags: shell-script

I have a bash script which checks if the `ACCESS_TOKEN` is equal to null it will exit.

```
ACCESS_TOKEN=$(jq -r '.access_token' <<<"$(curl --request GET \
  --url 'https://'$LANDSCAPE'/oauth/token/?grant_type=client_credentials' \
  -u "$CLIENT_ID":"$CLIENT_SECRET")")
if [[ -n $ACCESS_TOKEN -eq null ]]; then 
   exit 1
fi
```

or:

```
ACCESS_TOKEN=$(jq -r '.access_token' <<<"$(curl --request GET \
  --url 'https://'$LANDSCAPE'/oauth/token/?grant_type=client_credentials' \
  -u "$CLIENT_ID":"$CLIENT_SECRET")")
if [ -n "$ACCESS_TOKEN" -eq null ]; then 
   exit 1
fi
```

the console logs:

```
+ ACCESS_TOKEN=null
+ '[' -n null -eq null ']'
/tmp/jenkins6798373284183556496.sh: line 8: [: too many arguments
```

It seems that the `if condition` is not working well.

Comment: Hard to guess what you're doing. What you posted has 6 lines, the error message states error on line 8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to check if the string is not empty **and** if it is "null", a better syntax is:

```
if [ -n "$ACCESS_TOKEN" ] && [ "$ACCESS_TOKEN" = "null" ] 
then 
   exit 1
fi
```

As @Tomaz correctly states, you cannot check both premisses at once using Bash syntax.

As @Kusanalanda also points out, the first test is irrelevant, and was just to make a point/explain `if` usage. Following the logic, if $ACCESS_TOKEN is tested again the **string** "null", then it is already implicit the string cannot be empty, so actually this can be rewritten as:

```
if [ "$ACCESS_TOKEN" = "null" ] 
then 
   exit 1
fi
```

Comment: It seems as if the `-n` test is not needed. If the variable contains no value, it will not be equal to the string `null` (if that is supposed to be a string at all, sometimes people seems to thing it's a special value that denotes "no value").

Comment: @Kusalananda Yeah, I just wrote this for the benefit of the understanding and syntax of the OP, besides being short in time. I also noticed the first condition is redundant. As for the actual string "null", some utilities indeed return "null" as a full string, in specific situations when they have nothing else to return or have not met a condition...`jq` is one of them, for instance, and in the past I found more doing that.

Comment: @Kusalananda taken from a script of mine here using `jq` too: `if [ x"$S" == x"null" ] # end of array`

Comment: @Tomaz is incorrect (though I could not find the referenced post). `[` is not bash syntax and you cannot use `&&` inside since `[` is a command. bash syntax (`[[`) does support using `&&` and `||` inside its test operators. Regardless, testing `-n` has no effect in this particular case

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:

```
[ -n "$ACCESS_TOKEN" -eq null ]
```

`[` is the test operator and it can check either:

- if a string value is not zero - when you use `-n`
- compare two integers - when you use `-eq`

But not both at once! (Not in this form at least.) So you have to pick what you want to check in this `[`. And if you want to compare to `null`, then it would be a string comparison, which is done with the `=` operator.

Comment: ... which is done with the `=` operator.

Comment: @MichaelHomer Are they not equivalent in Bash?

Comment: They are functionally equivalent in Bash, but documented as "`=` should be used with the test (`[`) command" (because `=` is in POSIX and `==` is not). It wasn't wrong.

Comment: @MichaelHomer The shell is not defined in the question, so it might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You could use shell's

> Parameter Expansion
>   .
>   .
>   .
>          **${parameter:-word}**
>                 Use Default Values.  If parameter is unset or null, the expansion of word is substituted.

like

```
if [ "${ACCESS_TOKEN:-x}" = null ]; then echo Yes; else echo No; fi;
```

Be aware that it is the literal string "null" in the `test`, not the null "attribute" of the variable.